# Have my application use data from a file with an associated extension

Tags: macos, file-association

I have a game application and I am incorporating Aquatic Prime into it for authentication. When user purchases my application, I plan to email them the AquaticPrime key via an associated file. Then have the user double click the associated file and if the the key is valid open the application. No copying/pasting or typing long serial numbers. At this point, I have successfully associated a file extension with the application and have the AquaticPrime functioning in the application. But I don't understand how to get access to the information in the associated file when my app opens from double clicking the associated file. Any leads would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you try to go to your `main` function and `NSLog` the values of `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: It took me awhile but I finally got the information out of argv. I ran the following code:  <br/>    ` int arg;
    for (arg = 0; arg < argc; ++arg)
    {
        printf("Arg %d is %s\n", arg, argv[arg]);
    }`
Unfortunate argv is only passing one string, the name of my application not any information about the associated file that was double clicked to open the application.

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand what your question was. I've re-read it more carefully. When you double click on a document file in the finder, your app delegate should receive `application:openFile:`. Did you implement that? Isn't it been called?

Comment: Thanks very much Analog File your last comment really helped me and I solved the problem. I had already set my AppController as NSApp's delegate. So I implemented NSApp's delegate method -(BOOL) application: (NSApplication *) theApplication openFile: (NSString *) filename. From there it was simple to use the filename to get the contents of the file!!! Thanks again.